# Ten identical balls are free to move in a box. Find the probability that they are in one half of the box at any given time.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am pretty much an amateur in probability. I came across two solutions to it:

The first one created a set of the possibility of number of balls in each half:

(Half 1, Half 2)= (0,10),(1,9),(2,8),...(10,0)

Based on this solution, the answer provided was 2/11 (since there are a total number of 11 possibilities and 2 are favourable).

The second solution was, 2/(2^10), using the equation:

[image: 1]

Such problems have already been solved for the one box remaining empty (which would be in this case because there are two boxes)

[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056038/probability-of-exactly-one-empty-box-when-n-balls-are-randomly-placed-in-n-boxes)

I don't understand how and why the solutions are different, and which one to follow.

Answer (score 2):

The first solution is false. Each alternative have not the same odds. You are not considering that, for example the solution (2 8) has a lot of more combinations than (0 10). That's because for (2 8), the 2 balls at your left can be any pair of the your 10 balls. The second solutions seems ok to me :D.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question need a little clarification. If you choose in advance the region limiting half the box the answer look simple every ball has a chance 50/50 to be in the selected region so the probability that all of them being in this precise region will be .5^10. Of course if you consider the other half you will have twice this number which is really small. 
A much more difficult problem will be if all the ball are so close that can be enclosed in a polygon  non larger than half box.